# Query to extract seeded/custom reports from Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle-ebs

What is the query to extract seeded/custom reports (concurrent requests - long name of the program) from Oracle EBS containing also the last run time of that request and the responsibility (from which program is run)?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FND Concurrent Requests Summary](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-concurrent-requests-summary/) blitz report. If you need the details, these are in the [FND Concurrent Requests](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-concurrent-requests/) query.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for the help. Can I extract the following parameters: Concurrent program name, Program last run date, Responsibility name from which it is run, Execution file name, Execution method?

Comment: I am getting the below error:
ORA-00904: "XXEN_UTIL"."USER_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 363 Column: 1

Comment: Hi Bumbi, yes, you have the execution file name and method in both reports. There are utility functions used from the xxen_util package, which you can download from the following link: https://www.enginatics.com/xxen_util/true

Comment: Or alternatively, you can either remove the functions, or, if you are using 19c, you can use the functions from xxen_util in a with clause construct in the SQL like this: with
function time(p_seconds in number) return varchar2 is
... select time(x.execution_seconds) execution_time from...

Answer (score 0):

The table fnd_conc_prog_onsite_info contains [summary information about concurrent requests](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22953/T174296T575591.htm). Unfortunately, this table does not capture the responsibility used to run the most recent request. One must look in the fnd_concurrent_requests table for the responsibility. However, it is possible that the concurrent request data has been purged. It will not be possible to determine the responsibility for purged requests unless one has some coding/auditing to capture the responsibility for those requests.

```
SELECT fcp.user_concurrent_program_name
      ,fcpoi.last_run_date
      ,fr.responsibility_name
FROM   fnd_conc_prog_onsite_info fcpoi
       JOIN fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcp
         ON (fcp.application_id = fcpoi.program_application_id
             AND fcp.concurrent_program_id = fcpoi.concurrent_program_id)
       JOIN fnd_application fa
         ON (fcp.application_id = fa.application_id)
       LEFT JOIN fnd_concurrent_requests fcr
         ON (fcr.request_id = fcpoi.last_run_request_id)
       LEFT JOIN fnd_responsibility_vl fr
         ON (fcr.responsibility_application_id = fr.application_id
             AND fcr.responsibility_id = fr.responsibility_id)
WHERE  fcpoi.last_run_date IS NOT NULL
AND    fa.application_short_name NOT LIKE 'XX%' -- exclude programs under custom applications
```